# Amazon Greengrass Docker deployments: docker-compose not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-iot-greengrass

I am trying to use AWS Greengrass to deploy docker containers to IoT devices (the devices have docker installed on them already) and am following the instructions provided by AWS to do this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/run-docker-container.html

Basically, I created a component using the GDK CLI, with the command

```bash
gdk component init -l python -t HelloWorld
```

For context, this is what my `recipe.yaml` file looks like:

```yaml
RecipeFormatVersion: '2020-01-25'
ComponentName: com.example.DockerTest
ComponentVersion: '1.0.0'
ComponentDescription: 'Uses Greengrass to deploy NodeRed and Mosquitto to docker containers on the IoT devices.'
ComponentPublisher: Amazon
ComponentDependencies:
  aws.greengrass.DockerApplicationManager:
    VersionRequirement: ~2.0.0
Manifests:
  - Platform:
      os: all
    Lifecycle:
        run: docker-compose -f {artifacts:path}/docker-compose.yaml up
    Artifacts:
      - URI: "docker:nodered/node-red:latest"
      - URI: "docker:eclipse-mosquitto:latest"
      - URI: "s3://<valid s3 path>/docker-compose.yml"
```

And this is the `docker-compose.yml` file stored in the s3 bucket:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  nodered:
    image: "nodered/node-red:latest"
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
  mqtt:
    image: "eclipse-mosquitto:latest"
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
```

When I deployed it to my raspberry pi at home, however, I got this error in the component logs on the raspberry pi, which has docker installed:

```
[WARN] (Copier) com.smartbeej.DockerTest: stderr. sh: 1: docker-compose: not found.
```

Running `docker container ls` on the raspberry pi showed no containers running as well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some peer progamming, I have figured out the solution:

`docker-compose` does not refer to the `docker-compose.yml` file. It instead refers to the `docker-compose` **command**. To fix this, you can do one of two things:

1. Install the `docker-compose` command on your IoT device: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/standalone/
2. Install the `docker compose` plugin on your IoT device: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/ 
   and change the Lifecycle command in the `recipe.yaml` from `docker-compose` to `docker compose`